# Inducing representations from a subgroup of finite index.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and  $H$ a subgroup of finite index. Let $(\sigma , W) $ be a irreducible representation of $H$ (which need not be finite dimensional).

1) When can we extend this representation of $H$ to a representation of $G$?

2) If we cannot, then we can always induce this representation of $H$ to a representation,say $(\pi , V)$, of $G.$ Is there anything we can conclude about $\pi $ in terms of irreducibility and/or its relation with $\sigma$.

We have a similar kind of result in the case of finite groups using Mackey Theory, but can we say anything when the groups are infinite?

Edit 1: Here the groups are assumed to be real reductive Lie groups. And if needed the representations are admissible.

It will be helpful even if you point me to some reference. Thanks.

Comment: At the moment, this is really far too general for there to be an answer. The extension problem and the decomposition of an induced representation are both extremely difficult problems, where not much is known in complete generality. Do you have any specific classes of groups in mind (topological if they're "big"; larger groups with the discrete topology are pretty hopeless)? Certainly, in some cases (definitely profinite, compact and for connected, reductive groups over local fields provided $H$ satisfies certain hypotheses), there is a generalization of Mackey's theorem.

Comment: However, it's hard to say anything much beyond that right now. Maybe you have some certain classes of groups in mind, together with some properties which you might like to hold?

Comment: I suppose, as a rough guide, here are some cases where it might be possible to say something: finite groups (as you seem to know), profinite groups (essentially equivalently), compact groups, Lie groups, algebraic groups over local fields, algebraic groups over an arbitrary field under the Zariski topology. More generally, whenever all irreducibles are finite-dimensional you can probably say something (as long as the topology isn't too "weird").

Comment: @PL The groups for which I am trying to figure out things are real reductive Lie groups. And the representations are admissible representations. In fact if it helps I also have that the subgroup is of index 2. And thanks for the comment I will make a note of the fact that I am dealing with Lie groups in the question.